# CoffeeScript - Accessing instance variable and jQuery element

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I would like to use a jQuery element in an iterative function, while maintaining access to a class' instance variables.

**For example:**

```
class MyClass

  myVar: true

  myFunction: =>
    $('div').each ->
      console.log @.myVar # true?
      console.log $(this) # div?
```

Comment: @tymeJV No, the code doesn't look fine at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question you asked is: Use the fat arrow with `each` to maintain the value of `@`, and use the index/element arguments being passed to `each` to access the element:

```
myFunction: =>
  $('div').each (i, e) =>
    console.log @myVar
    console.log $(e)
```

Also, use `@myVar` instead of `@.myVar` (both will work, but `@.myVar` is far from idiomatic).

The *better* answer to what you're actually trying to do is, avoid `each` and use CoffeeScript's `for/in`:

```
myFunction: ->
  for div in $('div')
    console.log @myVar # true
    console.log $(div) # div
```